# How can I recover a github wiki page after changing its name to begin with an underscore?

Tags: github

The title pretty much covers it.  I renamed a page in a repository's wiki so it started with an underscore and it disappeared from the "Pages" list.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with my own repo just now, as a test. Happy hunting.

```sh
git clone git@github.com:svnpenn/a.wiki.git
cd a.wiki
git mv _foo.md foo.md
git commit -m 'fix underscore'
git push
```